# How to save values from DataGrid in wpf

Tags: datagrid

I'd like to know how to save values from DataGrid in to the List or List. I need it because, want to send values from rows in to the database.

This is what I did.

```
               <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" CanUserAddRows="True" x:Name="DataGridDb" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Source= savePoperties}">
                <DataGrid.Columns >
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data" Binding="{Binding Data}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="PersonName" Binding="{Binding Person}"/>
              
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

also I created class what contain those properties

```
public ObservableCollection<SaveDb> savePoperties = new ObservableCollection<ZapisDb>();
    public class SaveDb : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Data { get; set; }
        public string PersonName{ get; set; }

        public SaveDb()
        {

        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

and then I got method responsible for create rows in DataGrid.

```
public ObservableCollection<DataGrid> currentContactData = new ObservableCollection<DataGrid>();
private void RefreshDataGrid()
{
    DataGridDb.ItemsSource = null;
    DataGridDb.Columns[0].Width = 195;
    DataGridDb.Columns[1].Width = 195;
    DataGridDb.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate() { DataType = typeof(DataGrid) };
    DataGridDb.ApplyTemplate();
    DataGridDb.CanUserAddRows = true;
    DataGridDb.CanUserDeleteRows = true;
    DataGridDb.ItemsSource = currentContactData;
    DataGridDb.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
}
```

Q: How to save values in to the ObservableCollection savePoperties?
I quess, that need to add button "save"  with Click="Save" method and how it should looke like in code behind c#??

```
public void Save(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do it.
First delete

```
public ObservableCollection<SaveDb> savePoperties = new ObservableCollection<ZapisDb>();

public ObservableCollection<DataGrid> currentContactData = new ObservableCollection<DataGrid>();
private void RefreshDataGrid()
{
    DataGridDb.ItemsSource = null;
    DataGridDb.Columns[0].Width = 195;
    DataGridDb.Columns[1].Width = 195;
    DataGridDb.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate() { DataType = typeof(DataGrid) };
    DataGridDb.ApplyTemplate();
    DataGridDb.CanUserAddRows = true;
    DataGridDb.CanUserDeleteRows = true;
    DataGridDb.ItemsSource = currentContactData;
    DataGridDb.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
}
```

then create field

```
public List<SaveDb> values{get; set;}
```

-in constructor initialize:

```
values = new List<SaveBb>();
```

-xaml
inside of DataGrid add:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" CanUserAddRows="True" x:Name="DataGridDb" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path = values, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Person ID" Binding="{Binding Path= Id , Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date of today" Binding="{Binding Path= Data , Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Person" Binding="{Binding Path=PersonName , Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

add some button:

```
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Click="Save" Content="save" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Background="CornflowerBlue" 
                    Margin="15"/>
```

inside of method save you can do magic with list of values  for examle

```
public void Save(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
     values.Id = value.Id;
     values.Data = value.Data;
     values.PersonName = value.Pobierajacy;

    }
    SaveToDataBase(values);
}
```

Thank you:)

Comment: then create field public List<values>{get; set;}

-in constructor initialize: values = new List<values>();

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your ObservableCollection on click of save button i.e

```
private class YourClass
{
    public string column1 { get; set; }
    public string column2 { get; set; }
}

public ObservableCollection<YourClass> currentContactData = new ObservableCollection<YourClass>();

public void Save(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(YourClass item in currentContactData)
    {
        var col1 = item.column1.ToString().Trim();
        var col2 = item.column2.ToString().Trim();
        
        // Now Insert Your Values to Database
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Just Added how to do it upper:)